# Pentaho query on Greenplum stays in 'idle in transaction'

Tags: postgresql, pentaho-data-integration, greenplum

In my Pentaho transformation, I use (amongst others) the following steps:

1. **Execute SQL script** - to drop and recreate a table on an Oracle DB (destination stage table, used in partition swap later)
2. **Table Input** - select data from a Greenplum (PostgreSQL) table
3. **Oracle bulk loader** - to populate the table that was prepared in step 1 with the data from step 2

The problem is that step 2 does not execute. The query is visible in pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity, but the state remains as "*idle in transaction*".

Which as I understand means that it is not doing anything (https://dataegret.com/2015/11/introduction-to-pg_stat_activity/).

When I run the query from DBeaver is returns the data without any issues.

Does anyone know why my query is showing such behaviour?